# SQLAlchemy - How to process a column before it is committed?

Tags: python, orm, insert, sqlalchemy

I have a simple User class http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    password = Column(Text) # should be a hash
```

how would I be able to moidyf my User class or listen for an event so that I can change the password to a salted version before it's commited? Rather than doing `user.name = salted(username)` each time, I would like it built into the User class somehow.

```
user = User(name='test', password='hashme')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) # get a factory
mySession = Session()
mySession.add(user)
mySession.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    password = Column(Text) # should be a hash

    @staticmethod
    def _hash_password(mapper, connection, target):
        user = target
        user.password = hash_method(user.password)


listen(User, 'before_insert', User._hash_password)
listen(User, 'before_update', User._hash_password)
```